# MSI Installer Package for multiple versions of dll files

Tags: vb.net, windows-installer

I am working on a MSI Installer for a small windows application tool. On adding newer version and creating the MSI Installer, we have to uninstall the older files and install the newer version.

How should i handle version installation ? How the Continuous Integration Deployment method works ? On a every installation, does the old dll's are deleted and newer version dll's are placed.

Comment: What tool are you using to create the installer? If it is Installshield, Advanced Installer or similar there are views that will help you create a "major upgrade" which Phil describes below. If you use WIX there are threads that describe how a major upgrade should be implemented here on stackoverflow. I will add a quick, general answer too with some upgrade pointers, but we really need to know what tool you are using to answer properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something called DLL isolation , for windows installer designed to get you out of DLL hell take a look at this MSDN article, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369732(v=vs.85).aspx or you could use the product code upgrade code to upgrade via windows installer

Comment: here's another link about product codes http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/10/understanding-msi.aspx

Comment: link which you provide doesnt talk about versioning and installing the newer files

Comment: my bad was rushing try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372399(v=vs.85).aspx and this http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want your newer MSI product to uninstall all the older files and install the newer ones you need a major upgrade that sequences RemoveExistingProducts early in the install. That assumes you just want everything removed as if it was manually uninstalled and then the new one installed. You do need to increment the ProductVersion of your MSI in the first three digits and do whatever else your tool provides to do a major upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You generally maintain the setup source file as a regular code file. You update it, version control it and keep it as similar as possible across releases. What format this setup file is in will obviously depend on the tool you use.

Trivialised release process:

- You create yourself a release area, dump files there from the first
  release, then make an installer with whatever tool you use.
- For the next version of your application
  you do the same, dump files in the release area, include any new
  files in your setup, delete removed files from your setup, update version numbers in the setup and make a major upgrade out of the new version so that it uninstalls the old version before installing the new one.
- For further releases you update the setups major upgrade logic (or you make this automatic via an automatic build process) and add / remove files and registry settings in your setup as appropriate. Then test the setup thoroughly on clean and upgrade machines alike.

I don't know if this answers your question, but let's hear back from you.